# Setting up git with similar apps

Tags: ios, git, sourcetree

I am a new to using .git and I have three IOS apps that all have little changes from each other. I need to know how I can set up something on source tree so when I push one update to one of the apps the rest will have that change. I do not know much about git but if any one could help me that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is probably an Xcode answer rather than a git answer. I would suggest creating a single Xcode project that has multiple targets. Each target would build one of your 3 apps, with the common source and assets shared between the targets.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create a clone project, always fork it. So you can always push the changes in either project.
If this is not the case, select the changes in your project in source tree and create a patch through it. On the other project, apply that patch. You will get all the changes.